# I cant see webform result

Tags: 7, webforms

My webform seem fine except I cant see the result. When I click result, it will state Server error 500. All my webforms face same problem. I had tried create new webform and tried again. As a result, same problem. FYI. This website is duplicated from another website by copy files and database and place it at another domain. Here is my question: How to check what is the actual problem?

Comment: Can u tell the error which you are getting in Database Log, by going to /admin/reports/dblog.

Go to webform result page, after that go to admin/reports/dblog, and clear the error. After that reload the result page and see if any error comes.

You can also check the apache error config, by going to /var/log/apache2 and do tail -100 error.log

Comment: @ManojBisht Thank you!!! One of my file went missing....Now its fine.